# What is the best way to get several serial digital \$n\$ bits while adding them?

Tags: digital-logic

I need to design a digital circuit that gets incoming \$n\$ parallel inputs, add each incoming n bits, and each sum is placed in an \$n\$ flip-flops, overriding what is previously stored on the flip-flops.

In summary, the circuit solves the difference equation:
$$
Y_{\text{present state of N FFlops in decimal}}(x)= Y(x-1)+X_{\text{arbitrary input in decimal}}
$$

My plan is to create a feedback path from the storage flip-flops to the adder as shown below

[image: circuit sample]

My input is a parallel n-bit input that will be fed into the input 1 terminal of the parallel adder. The output of the adder is also parallel and will be fed into the D flip-flops for storage. The stored data in the FFlops will be fed back to the the adder so that it can be added again to the next arbitrary input.

Is this design acceptable?

Edit:

Andy aka's comment below solved my question and pointed out that this is a numerical integrator and the clock speed must be clocked slowly, which I think must be sufficient for the interval of the incoming inputs.

Comment: It's called a numerical integrator and, for your design, it needs to be clocked slowly so that it doesn't integrate at Max rate and give useless cycling modulos answers.

Comment: @Andy aka thank you for that, however may I ask why the clock should be slow? If the clock is sufficiently high, the timing problem should not occur since the the data is saved by the flip-flop with sufficient time for the edge transitions

Comment: "...add them one by one" in series or in parallel? Why keep these sums in n-FFs? What is the goal of this exercise? and what is the standard name for this circuit?

Comment: @Syed I meant  add each incoming parallel input. Let me edit the question

Comment: @qcpz Are you looking to create a bit-serial CPU? If so, [these already exist](https://diode.zone/w/0230a518-e207-4cf6-b5e2-69cc09411013). They've won awards, too. And they are free. Just download them and cut out the parts you want.

Comment: Look at what you have drawn and tell me what will stop the output numerically ramping and cycling from zero to full scale in nano seconds.

Comment: @jonk let me look into that, we have only covered combination and sequential circuits so it might take a while for me to digest that

Comment: @qcpz Olaf has written a lot! And made it very very easy to understand, too. Nice videos. Tons of source code. And, very likely, you can just write and talk with him. I'm pretty sure he'd be helpful.

Comment: @qcpz Next year I'll be using his work here as a learning experience as well as for practical uses. (Unless something still better arrives. But I doubt it.)

Comment: Please edit your question and explain why you are doing this, what the application is and what the data source is. Plenty of explanation, not just one line on each. The solution is all in the requirements, which are nearly all missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is this design acceptable?*

It's called a numerical integrator and, for your design, it needs to be clocked slowly so that it doesn't integrate at Max rate and give useless cycling modulus numbers at the output. It needs to be clocked: -

[image]

> *In summary, the circuit solves the difference equation:*
>
> \$Y_{\text{present state of N FFlops in decimal}}(x)=Y(x−1)+X_{\text{arbitrary input in decimal}}\$

Then the time difference between Y(x) appearing after Y(x-1) appeared needs to be the clock period.

You might also choose to have a hold facility and a count reset facility.

> *Andy aka's comment below solved my question and pointed out that this
> is a numerical integrator and the clock speed must be clocked slowly,
> which I think must be sufficient for the interval of the incoming
> inputs.*

I've added a couple more things.

Answer (score 1):

It's called an accumulator, and one common use is as a numerical integrator per Andy's answer.

Beyond that, what you are asking is unclear.

Are the several serial N-bit inputs a discrete sequence, such as prices when food items are scanned at a supermarket checkout? If so, then every time a new item is scanned, you need precisely one clock pulse, otherwise you are either double-charging, or giving stuff away for free.

If they are a continuous sequence, like speed values, this is a numerical integrator which needs an appropriate clock rate to integrate speed (approximately measure distance). As Andy says, keeping the clock rate low means it will take longer to overflow, but this decreases the accuracy of your integration measurement.

An alternative is to use more than N flipflops (say 2 * N) and sign-extend the N-bit input to 2*N bits (or zero-extend if your input never represents negative quantities). That way you can integrate 0 to 100kph, even if you are travelling hundreds or thousands of kilometres. (You may remember cars that "rolled over" after 100,000km - most now have another digit or two)

A higher clock rate then measures speed more often, giving distance more accurately but accumulates larger values (like distance in metres or mm rather than in km)

Note that you didn't specify an initial value (always a problem in integration) : it is common to reset an accumulator to 0000 when you power on, (or before scanning a customer's shopping!) but if you need a car's total mileage to persist, you need to store it in something less volatile than flip-flops to survive battery changes...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it looks like adding a button for a user to save some data would solve the clock timing problem (connecting a push button directly to a clock input of the fflops)

Comment: If you're using that approach, be careful to debounce that button, or you'll double count. You can add a second "Clear" button to reset the accumulator.

Comment: Oh, is there a better approach than that? All I can think of now is to connect the button to a CLK and devise a sequential circuit that counts or waits at most "0.5 seconds" before a another button press is recorded to prevent the button from "debouncing"

Comment: There are various ways of debouncing, easily searchable. As designer, you get to choose according to your needs, which you know and I don't. As I said, your question is not clear.